# Regex: Difference between square brackets [] and vertical bar |

Tags: java, regex

I'm having trouble understanding the differences between square brackets [] and the vertical bar | in Regular Expressions.

For example: 
When I use this code in java to change the format of a String (Using |):

```
str = str.replaceAll("(\\d+|\\W)", "$0 ").replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim();
```

From: (12+((23+ 37) * (774*435)))

To: ( 12 + ( ( 23 + 37 ) * ( 774 * 435 ) ) )

Which is the desired output.

However, when I use this code, I get a different output (Using []):

```
str = str.replaceAll("[\\d+\\W]", "$0 ").replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim();
```

I get from: (12+((23+ 37) * (774*435)))

To: ( 1 2 + ( ( 2 3 + 3 7 ) * ( 7 7 4 * 4 3 5 ) ) )

Notice the spaces between the numbers (not desired).

So, can somebody please explain what is going on? Or what is the difference between [] and |?

Thank you.

Comment: Check out this link it's already answered Click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801630/what-is-the-difference-between-square-brackets-and-parentheses-in-a-regex "").

Comment: `|` is used to provide 'or' functionality when used within ()'s, while the `[]` denote character classes, as in match any of the characters/symbols inside the `[]` for the specified number of characters denoted by the following `?*+{#}` specifiers, or if a `^` is used, it means __don't__ match that symbol.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801630/what-is-the-difference-between-square-brackets-and-parentheses-in-a-regex).

The vertical bar is a regex "or" means "a or b"

Square brackets are a character class meaning "any character from a or b.

[Character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) is a shorthand for "or". From this [explanation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

- If you want to match an a or an e use [ae]
- A character class matches only a single character.
- You can also use hyphen to specify a range such as [0-9] or [a-e]

Answer (score 2):

The brakcets (`[]`) negate the effect of the `+`.  So when you have `[\\d+\\W]`, that matches a single character (digit, `+` or non-word)

Comment: +1, I wonder why you've been downvoted.