# RegEx Python issue

Tags: python, json, regex

RegEx Expression:

```
[Height|Length|Width|Depth]:\D*\s*(\d*\.*-*\d*)-*\D*\s*  [Height|Length|Width|Depth]:\D*\s*(\d*\.*-*\d*)-*\D*\s*[Height|Length|Width|Depth]:\D*\s*(\d*\.*-*\d)*-*\D*\s*
```

Input Text - JSON TEXT

```
{"Product Type":["Printer Cartridges"],"Product Name":["Xerox - Yellow - toner cartridge ( equivalent to: HP CB382A ) - for HP Color LaserJet CM6030 CM6040 CP6015"],"Brand":["XEROX"],"Product Long Description":["<!-- CNET Content -->Toner cartridges for HP printers from Xerox deliver brilliant image quality and excellent reliability at a low cost. Compared to the original HP toner cartridge youll get better or equal page yield pay around 25% less. Get more pay less without risk.<br><br><h3 id=detailspecs>Specifications</h3><span class=font_size3bold>General</span><br>&nbsp;<img align=absmiddle src=http://images.highspeedbackbone.net/main/gfx-blkbullet.jpg>&nbsp;&nbsp;Compatible Cartridge: &nbsp;HP CB382A<br><br><span class=font_size3bold>Consumable</span><br>&nbsp;<img align=absmiddle src=http://images.highspeedbackbone.net/main/gfx-blkbullet.jpg>&nbsp;&nbsp;Consumable Type: &nbsp;Toner cartridge<br>&nbsp;<img align=absmiddle src=http://images.highspeedbackbone.net/main/gfx-blkbullet.jpg>&nbsp;&nbsp;Printing Technology: &nbsp;Laser<br>&nbsp;<img align=absmiddle src=http://images.highspeedbackbone.net/main/gfx-blkbullet.jpg>&nbsp;&nbsp;Color: &nbsp;Yellow<br>&nbsp;<img align=absmiddle src=http://images.highspeedbackbone.net/main/gfx-blkbullet.jpg>&nbsp;&nbsp;Included Qty: &nbsp;1-pack<br>&nbsp;<img align=absmiddle src=http://images.highspeedbackbone.net/main/gfx-blkbullet.jpg>&nbsp;&nbsp;Duty Cycle: &nbsp;Up to 23500 pages at 5% coverage<br><br><span class=font_size3bold>Compatibility Information</span><br>&nbsp;<img align=absmiddle src=http://images.highspeedbackbone.net/main/gfx-blkbullet.jpg>&nbsp;&nbsp;Compatible with: &nbsp;HP Color LaserJet CM6030 MFP CM6030f MFP CM6040 MFP CM6040f MFP CP6015de CP6015dn CP6015n CP6015x CP6015xh<br><!-- END CNET Content -->"],"Item ID":["41057188"],"Product Segment":["Electronics"],"UPC":["095205855838"]}
```

**Problem**:

RegEx should check in JSON text if one of these `words --> (Height or Width or Length or Depth)` are there then fetch the value.

Since above given JSON text doesn't have this kind of value it should not find anything but my RegEx is finding undesirable value. I think I am missing something in RegEx.

Edit:

For this input JSON - I should be be able to extract Height, Length, Width or Depth:

```
{"Brand":["Concord Fans"],"Energy Guide: Appliance Labeling Rule Required":["N"],"Country of Origin: Components":["USA and/or Imported"],"Product Short Description":["Height: 6.2."],"Actual Color":["Multicolor"],"Product Segment":["Clothing, Shoes & Accessories"],"Color":["Multicolor"],"Product Name":["Concord Fans RM-08 Remote & Wall Control Set"],"Product Type":["Televisions"],"Manufacturer Part Number":["RM-08"],"Manufacturer":["Concord Fans"],"Category":["TVs"],"Product Long Description":["Height: 6-2- Width: 8-8- Length: 8-8- Energy Star: No- Energy Saver: No- UL Classification: UL Certified- UL Application: Dry SKU: CNCD467"],"GTIN":["00014592213038"],"Number of Batteries":["0"],"E-Waste Recycling Compliance Required":["N"],"UPC":["014592213038"]}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the json library? https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: Can you give an example of the undesirable value, and the sample JSON that returned that value?

Comment: Undesired Value I am getting on running this regex and input value is:  ['1-', '', '23500']

Comment: Edit your question with that info please.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea, in general, to parse JSON data with regular expressions, but you definitely have something wrong in this part of the regular expression:

```
[Height|Length|Width|Depth]
```

This would, for instance, match a single "H":

```
>>> re.search("[Height|Length|Width|Depth]", "H").group()
'H'
```

It looks like you've meant to use a [*non-capturing group here*](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups):

```
(?:Height|Length|Width|Depth)
```

See also:

- [What is the difference between square brackets and parentheses in a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9801630/771848)

Comment: I have updated my post with an example that should be able to extract information. Can you please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

It looks that your data is json compatiable- So try `json` module instead-Details [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html). After converting into json you can access using regular dictionary key as `d['Product Long Description']` and thereafter you can use many way to extract any information from that - I just showed one way to go-

```
import json,re

s = """{"Brand":["Concord Fans"],"Energy Guide: Appliance Labeling Rule Required":["N"],"Country of Origin: Components":["USA and/or Imported"],"Product Short Description":["Height: 6.2."],"Actual Color":["Multicolor"],"Product Segment":["Clothing, Shoes & Accessories"],"Color":["Multicolor"],"Product Name":["Concord Fans RM-08 Remote & Wall Control Set"],"Product Type":["Televisions"],"Manufacturer Part Number":["RM-08"],"Manufacturer":["Concord Fans"],"Category":["TVs"],"Product Long Description":["Height: 6-2- Width: 8-8- Length: 8-8- Energy Star: No- Energy Saver: No- UL Classification: UL Certified- UL Application: Dry SKU: CNCD467"],"GTIN":["00014592213038"],"Number of Batteries":["0"],"E-Waste Recycling Compliance Required":["N"],"UPC":["014592213038"]}"""

d=json.loads(json.loads(json.dumps(s)))
print d['Product Long Description']
print ''.join(d['Product Long Description']).split(":")[0:4]
print [filter(len,y) for y in re.findall(r'Height:\s*([\d.]+-[\d.]+)|Width:\s*([\d.]+-[\d.]+)|Length:\s*([\d.]+-[\d.]+)',''.join(d['Product Long Description']))]
```

Output-

```
[u'Height: 6-2- Width: 8-8- Length: 8-8- Energy Star: No- Energy Saver: No- UL Classification: UL Certified- UL Application: Dry SKU: CNCD467']
[u'Height', u' 6-2- Width', u' 8-8- Length', u' 8-8- Energy Star']
[(u'6-2',), (u'8-8',), (u'8-8',)]
```

Comment: I didn't understand the last print statement, how did u extract. it will be helpful if u can explain briefly.

Comment: `r'\w+:'` means to split a string by `:` that have one or more word char i.e. a-z and 0-9 before.