# Regex expression not match line of Node.js code

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I am looking for a regex that can match any line of code that contains a single reference to a core module)

Something like this:

```
const coreModuleMatches = /'^[var|const]{0,1}[a-z\$\_]{1,}=require([\'|"][assert|fs|path][\'|"])[;|,]{0,1}$/;
```

This should match all of these lines

```
var pth = require("path"); 
const asrt = require('assert'),
     fs = require('fs'),
     cp = require('child_process');
```

The problem is I can't get the simple regex to work, so my more complex regex currently has no hope.

I am stripping out all whitespace except newline characters before matching the code with regular expressions, and then splitting by newline so that I can go line by line through the code. Any ideas welcome.

Comment: You forgot to escape `(` and `)`.

Comment: Is string from `var. . . . . ('child_process');` one match or two different matches ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801630/what-is-the-difference-between-square-brackets-and-parentheses-in-a-regex

Comment: var. . . . . ('child_process'); is one match, and the subexpression I really care about is simply 'child_process', I just want an array of core-modules that are referenced in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from forgetting to escape `(` and `)` there were **few** mistakes in your regex too.

**Your Regex:**

`/'^[var|const]{0,1}[a-z\$\_]{1,}=require([\'|"][assert|fs|path][\'|"])[;|,]{0,1}$/`

**My Regex:**

`/^(?:var|const)\s*([a-z$_]+\s*=\s*require\(('|")(?:assert|fs|path|child_process)\2\),?[\n\r\t\s]*)*;$/`

**Explanation:**

- `(?:var|const)\s*([a-z$_]+\s*=\s*` This matches from `var` or `const` upto the variable name followed by `=` including all whitespaces.
- `require\(('|")(?:assert|fs|path|child_process)\2\),?` This matches the `require()` and whatever the module is inside it. As the first `quote` is captured using `('|")`, `\2` implies that it's the one repeated while closing too, so that mismatching of quotes does not takes place.
- `[\n\r\t\s]*)*;` This matches all the whitespaces in your second variable consisting of newlines, tabs, spaces, carriage returns.

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bB4jR2/1)**</kbd>

Comment: thanks, I actually don't need to match whitespace. If you could simplify your regex by removing whitespace matches and explain how yours works that would help!

Comment: @AlexMills: Which whitespaces would you like to be removed ? In your question the match from `const.....` till end have many whitespaces. Besides that you haven't answered to my comment on your question.

Comment: yeah, don't worry about that, it still works with the optional whitespace...I don't know what the '\2\' is doing. Your answer is unlikely to help anyone unless you can explain the regex a bit, thanks

Comment: @AlexMills: I have updated the answer with explanation. Let me know if it's clear or not.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regex so complicated, something like `/("|')(assert|fs|http)\1/` should be enough:

```
// don't list all modules by hand
var builtinModules = require('builtin-modules');

console.time('end');
var input =
`var pth = require("path");
var _ = require('lodash');
const asrt = require('assert'),
fs = require('fs'),
cp = require('child_process');`.split('\n');

// \1 is a reference to the matched beginning (double)quote
// to prevent something like "path'/'fs" to match
var rgxStr = `("|')(${ builtinModules.join('|') })\\1`;
var rgx = new RegExp(rgxStr);
// console.log(rgxStr); // uncomment to see how the Regex looks like

var output = input.filter((line) => line.match(rgx));

console.timeEnd('end');
console.log('input');
console.log(input);
console.log('--------------------------------------');
console.log('output');
console.log(output);
```

Output:

```
end: 0.428ms
input
[ 'var pth = require("path");',
  'var _ = require(\'lodash\');',
  'const asrt = require(\'assert\'),',
  'fs = require(\'fs\'),',
  'cp = require(\'child_process\');' ]
--------------------------------------
output
[ 'var pth = require("path");',
  'const asrt = require(\'assert\'),',
  'fs = require(\'fs\'),',
  'cp = require(\'child_process\');' ]
```

Comment: You don't want to mismatch **quotes**. Use back-reference to captured groups.

Comment: I get this output, given this input:

Comment: input: var assert = require('assert');
const fs = require('fs');

Comment: output: core module match: 'assert'
core module match: '
core module match: assert
core module match: 'fs'
core module match: '
core module match: fs

Comment: so this regex is matching this literal: '  ... and also, it's matching 'assert' or assert , etc.

Comment: I have to capture '/" to check if the closing quote is the same as the opening, you could just grab match[1] instead of logging the entire array. Or, if you're sure the input is valid JS, you can use this regex: `var rgxStr = \`(?:"|')(${ builtinModules.join('|') })(?:"|')\`;`. And no, it doesn't match `assert` alone, only if it's between quotes.