# regex expression in javascript not working as expected

Tags: javascript, regex

we are trying to find if the given string is a valid indian mobile number or not

**valid indian mobile number**

1. starts with `7 or 8 or 9`
2. followed by 9 same or different numbers

here is my JavaScript for matching it, but unfortunately it returns false even when number is correct

```
var mobile_number = $('#number').val();
var mobile_regex = new RegExp('/^[789]\d{9}$/');
if(mobile_regex.test(mobile_number) == false) {
    console.log("not valid");
} else {
    console.log("valid");
}
```

Comment: What is a correct number?  [https://regex101.com/r/yW6vC2/1](https://regex101.com/r/yW6vC2/1) Here I can see that 7123456789 is a match, for example. Are there any other symbols at the front/back of the number?

Comment: `var mobile_regex = /^[789]\d{9}$/;`

Comment: @MariaDeleva anything followed by 7,8,9 but length must be equal to 10

Comment: @anubhava what is the difference with the current approach? Just wondering: doesn't `RegExp()` allow `\d`?

Comment: Perhaps, you can try this: `var mobile_regex = new RegExp('^[789]\d{9}$');`

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801630/what-is-the-difference-between-square-brackets-and-parentheses-in-a-regex

Comment: @fedorqui: 2 problems. `RegExp` doesn't need regex delimiter `/` and it requires double escaping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
   var mobile_number = $('#number').val();
   var mobile_regex = new Regex("^[7-9][0-9]{9}$")
   if(mobile_regex.test(mobile_number) == false) {
   console.log("not valid");
   } else {
    console.log("valid");
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code has two problems. If you're using a RegExp object, you don't need `/` characters, and the `\` character needs to be escaped.

This would work:

```
var mobile_regex = new RegExp("^[789]\\d{9}");
```

Alternatively, if you want to use the other format, this would work:

```
if(!mobile_number.match(/^[789]\d{9}/)) {
    console.log("not valid");
} else {
    console.log("valid");
}
```

Comment: why when using new RegExp does \d need to be escaped. /?

Comment: It's just the `\ ` that needs to be escaped. The reason is that `\ ` is an escape character in javascript strings.