# Check if string ends with

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to check if a string ends with

```
- v{number}
```

So for example

```
hello world           false
hello world - v2      true
hello world - v       false
hello world - v88     true
```

Not entirely sure how to go about doing this RegEx.

```
var str = 'hello world - v1';
var patt = new RegExp("/^ - v\d*$/");
var res = patt.test(str);
console.log(res);
```

How could I fix the above RegEx?

Comment: use `- v\d+$`.......

Comment: You linked to a page in my answer but now your comment is gone. Note I updated explaining no need for `/` and double escaping of `\d`.

Comment: you can use `var patt = new RegExp(" - v[0-9]+$");`

Comment: @praveen Have you read the question and answer on that page before marking duplicate? It is non-sense. In that case length of end with is constant and ends with a particular character, here length is variable, like 'hello world - v1234567890'.

Comment: @harishkumar Done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use this without checking anything else in the beginning

```
- v\d+$
```

This way you make sure it ends with `- v` followed by at least one digit. See it live in https://regex101.com/r/pB6vP5/1

Then, your expression needs to be:

```
var patt = new RegExp("- v\\d+$");
```

As [stated by anubhava in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38121990/regex-expression-in-javascript-not-working-as-expected#comment63676626_38121990):

- No need for `/`
- Requires double escaping for `\d`.

```js
var str = 'hello world - v15';
var patt = new RegExp("- v\\d+$");
var res = patt.test(str);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: What's the `m` flag? You need to include that as well in the answer.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I don't know why you deleted your answer, the logic seemed right to me.

Comment: @PraveenKumar it is for multi-line matching. This way you can include different lines in regex101.com and all of them are matched individually.

Comment: Ah, now I understood why my answer didn't work, @TimBiegeleisen!

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yes, but do you need double escaping with `test()`?  I'm not sure about that.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes! We need to. The `RegExp` value.

Comment: @fedorqui Upvoted to apologize for defacing your answer via verbose comments ^ ^

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no need to apologize neither need to upvote for off-topic reasons : ) I learnt a lot from both the comment by anubhava few days ago and now your discussion with Praveen!

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that achieves the same results without a Regex. Worth giving it a try.

```
function stringEndsWithVersionNum(string) 
{
    var parts   = string.split('- v');
    if(parts[0] !== string) //if the string has '- v' in it
    {
        var number = parts[parts.length -1].trim();//get the string after -v
        return !isNaN(number) && number.length > 0;//if string is number, return true. Otherwise false.
    }
    return false; 
}
```

Please use like so:

```
stringEndsWithVersionNum('hello world - v32')//returns true
stringEndsWithVersionNum('hello world - v'); //returns false 
stringEndsWithVersionNum('hello world');     //returns false
```