# How to use specific website in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want the regex pattern to only match `a9.com` or `www.a9.com`
I have tried add `?` before www. `/?([www]+\.)+[\ba9\.com\b]/;` but it shows error..
Did I miss anything ?

hope this result

```
a9.com   true
www.a9.com  true
a91.com  false
www.a91.com   false
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c2wsds0g/

```
var str = 'a9.com';

var regexPattern = /([www]+\.)+[\ba9\.com\b]/;
var result = regexPattern.test(str);
console.log(result)
```

**only regex. not use split or other method**

Comment: Do you understand the purpose of square brackets in RegEx?

Comment: does that means group a pattern ??  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9801697/1775888

Comment: I tried this work `/(www\.\ba9\.com\b|\ba9\.com\b)/;`

Comment: It means [character set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-sets).

Comment: so I should not add it wrap a9.com, right?

Comment: You got it.  Also if you want `1 or 0` times, then `?` goes **after** a pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Regex sould do the trick:

```
(www\.)?a9\.com
```

The ´?´ quantifier, to make the group optional goes after the group, not before.

Bonus: I always test my regex with [regexpal.com](http://www.regexpal.com), you should try it. You´ll find a handy cheat sheet there too.

Comment: should I add \b in before and after to avoid .comm or wwww

Comment: `/\b(www\.)?\ba9\.com\b/;`

Comment: Yes, you can use word boundaries, like this: \b(www\.)?a9\.com\b

Comment: You should have posted that requirement in the original question. Anyway, this should work: \b((www\.|[^\.])a9\.com\b)