# Regex expression in Java not working

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to create a Regex expression in Java for an email address and I'm stuck. When I use some of the online Regex testers it works fine but in Java it doesn't seem to want to work.

Here's my expression:
`[a-zA-Z!$.&\\d]{4,24}[@][a-zA-Z]{2,}[.edu|.com|.net]`

It is supposed to be:

- a 4-24 character username that can have digits, ".", "&", "$", and
  "!" in it
- "@" character following
- at least 2 characters for the domain but can include stuff like
  "school.alt"
- and the ending can only be ".net", ".com", or ".edu".

Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Even if I test it against a simple email like "test@school.edu" it doesn't match.

Comment: Possibly related [What is the difference between square brackets and parentheses in a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9801697/256196)

Comment: Start with parts of the regexp and go step by step until you found out what part of it does not work as expected

Comment: Email addresses [are pretty weird](http://girders.org/2013/01/dont-rfc-validate-email-addresses.html) though. Consider if you really want this. (also, you domain currently can't include "school.alt").

Answer (score 3):

You could change the end of your regex to a non capturing group using the `|` or:

`(?:\.edu|\.com|\.net)`

Or as @Bohemian commented you could write this simpeler as `\.(?:edu|com|net)`

Right now you are using a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[.edu|.com|.net]`

[`[a-zA-Z!$.&\d]{4,24}[@][a-zA-Z]{2,}(?:\.edu|\.com|\.net)`](https://regex101.com/r/nZQkVV/1)

Comment: correct (except it's called a character *class*, not a character *set*), or simpler: `\.(?:edu|com|net)`

Comment: @Bohemian Ah ok, thank you! Then I guess the [first line](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) is not entirely correct: "With a "character class", also called "character set","

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your regular expression.

1. `\\d` will also validate the prrsian numbers, for example: `پنج` or `شش`. So you should use [0-9].
2. The braces around of `@` is not needed.
3. Last expresion `.edu|.com|.net` must be in round brackets. `(.edu|.com|.net)`. Because it is not a set of characters, it is a strict expressions. Also the dot can be put out of brackets. `\.(edu|com|net)`.

   4. You should to add `^` and `$` before and after regular expression for validate total string.

So you regular expression will be:
`^[a-zA-Z!$.&0-9]{4,24}@[a-zA-Z]{2,}\.(edu|com|net)$`