# Why is this regex expression not matching the string exactly?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match 'http://' and 'https://' exactly so that I can remove them from URLS, although I'm having some trouble as it is also matching letters within the URL itself.

Why is this and how can I fix it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why? Because `[^`…`]` indicates a negated character class—every character that is neither `h`, `t`, `p`, `s`, `:`, `/` nor `$` is matched. Why not just match `/https:\/\//` and remove it?

Comment: Yes good point, what if I want to look for and replace both https:// and http:// ?

Comment: Use `/https?:\/\//`, do not cram the regex pattern with constructs you do not need. Study [character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) by all means.

Answer (score 0):

The regex `[^https://$]`
means:

> Match any single character not present in the list "htps:/$"

Answer (score 0):

The regex you have means

```
 [^http://$]
```

Match anything except `h,t,p,:,/,$`

You can simply use `URL` api to get host name and if you want to replace only `http or http` you can use `replace`

```js
let urls = ['http://example.com/123', 'https://examples.com', 'example.com']

// to get hostname
urls.forEach(url => {
  if (/^https?:\/\//i.test(url)) {
    let parsed = new URL(url)
    console.log(parsed.hostname)
  } else {
    console.log(url)
  }
})

// to remove http or https
urls.forEach(url => {
  let replaced = url.replace(/^https?:\/\//i, '')
  console.log(replaced)
})
```

Comment: Yes good point, what if I want to look for and replace both https:// and http:// ?

Comment: @AKL012 the answer already covers both the cases

Comment: Thanks, and how to include other characters like '()' and '-'?

Comment: @AKL012 what do you mean by that ? can you please explain ? where you want to allow those characters ?

Answer (score 0):

As others have answered, `[^https://$]` doesn't work because `[^]` isn't a capture group asserting start-of-line, it's a negated character class. Your regex matches any character that is not one of the letters `h, t, p, s, :, /` literally.

The `[brackets]` describe a character class, while the `(parenthesis)` describe a capture group - probably what you were looking for. You can learn more about them [in this excellent answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9801697/7431860)

It looks a bit like you were trying to use the `^` and `$` symbols, but that's not a good idea for your particular regex. This would have asserted the start-of-line was before `h`, and the end-of-line was after `/`, meaning the regex would not match unless `https://` was the *only* thing in the string.

If you'd like to match `http://` and `https://`, this regex will do the trick: `(https{0,1}:\/\/)`

```regex
BREAKDOWN

(https{0,1}:\/\/)


(               )    capture this as a group
 http                match "http"
     s{0,1}          match 0 or 1 "s"
           :         match ":"
            \/\/     match "//" literally
```

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/6TZiMr/1/)

If you'd like to match characters like `()` and `-`, you can do so by escaping them, too:

```
\(\)\-    matches "()-" literally
```

Good luck!