# PCRE Regex conversion for zabbix

Tags: regex, pcre, zabbix

I currently monitor a page that prints the following health check

```
<status>
<link type="text/css" id="dark-mode" rel="stylesheet" href=""/>
<style type="text/css" id="dark-mode-custom-style"/>
<cache>ok</cache>
<databaseMaster>error</databaseMaster>
<databaseSlave>error</databaseSlave>
<redis>ok</redis>
<files>ok</files>
</status>
```

I do it by using the following trigger (this one works)

```
{host:web.page.regexp[{$HOST_IP},health/check,,[error|warning],,].str(error)}=1
```

However when trying to go into the detail parsing each individual line response (i.e. database master,
in line 5, it can show 3 values, ok, error, and warning, the expression i'm trying to get running goes (this doesn't work)

```
{host:web.page.regexp[{$HOST_IP},health/check,,[<databaseMaster>error|<databaseMaster>warning],,].str(error)}=1
```

However despite the syntax and that i can't find anything wrong with it, for the greater than and lower than symbols are not metacharacters, somehow i suspect my regex expression is wrong but i'm not sure how to translate it to [pcre](https://www.debuggex.com/cheatsheet/regex/pcre)
 so I can match the characters that I want to trigger the alert

Im also wondering if zabbix have a feature that would be better suited for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[<databaseMaster>error|<databaseMaster>warning]` - you're trying to match either `<databaseMaster>error` or `<databaseMaster>warning`, but you're actually matching one character from the list `<d,a,t,b,s,e,M,r,>,o,|,w,n,i,g`.

[Square brackets] in this case mean "match one character present in the list." Try a capture group instead, which will behave as you're expecting:

`(<databaseMaster>error|<databaseMaster>warning)`

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9801697/7431860) for more info on the difference between parenthesis and square brackets in a regex.