# regular expression: the outcome is not as expected

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
pattern = "[0-9]+[st|nd|rd|th]?"
str2 = "1st 1 2 3 4 5th "
a = re.findall(pattern, str2)
print(a)
```

Expected Output

```
['1st', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5th']
```

Actual Output

```
['1s', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5t']
```

Comment: Try replacing the square brackets with round brackets. https://regex101.com/r/aRhIp4/1

Comment: @user8408080, thank you very much! [st|nd|rd|th] really asks regex match s, t|n, d|r,d|t,h.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re
pattern = r'[0-9]+(?:st|nd|rd|th)?'
str2 = "1st 1 2 3 4 5th "
a = re.findall(pattern, str2)
print(a)
```

Output:
`['1st', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5th']`

Your mistake was to use square brackets instead of parentheses. Square brackets usually used to indicate a range (like 0-9) rather then "OR" which is what you wanted in the suffix. For further reading:
[What is the difference between square brackets and parentheses in a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801630/what-is-the-difference-between-square-brackets-and-parentheses-in-a-regex)

If you change only the parentheses, output will be as follow:

`[('1', 'st'), ('1', ''), ('2', ''), ('3', ''), ('4', ''), ('5', 'th')]`

This is still not what you wanted, so we made a second change to pattern: adding `?:` is the syntax that creates a non-capturing group (means "treat it as one group").

Comment: "[0-9]+(?:st|nd|rd|th)?"    Please use this expression to save the hassle of merging tuples :)

Comment: @PythonNewbie You're absolutely right. I'm editing my post