# How to merge multiple duplicate key names using python in a format like dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary, append

I had data in a format like dictionary where I the data had multiple duplicate keys repeated multiple times with strings in a list as values, I want to merge all the keys with the same name and their values, the data was happened to be in a format like dictionary but not an actual dictionary I am referring it as dictionary simply because of the way it was existed.

#Data I had looks like below,

```
"city":["New York", "Paris", "London"],
"country":["India", "France", "Italy"],
"city":["New Delhi", "Tokio", "Wuhan"],
"organisation":["ITC", "Google", "Facebook"],
"country":["Japan", "South Korea", "Germany"],
"organisation":["TATA", "Amazon", "Ford"]
```

I had 1000s of duplicate keys repeating with some repeated and unique values which I wanted merge or append based on key.

#Output Expected

```
"city":["New York", "Paris", "London", "New Delhi", "Tokio", "Wuhan"],
"country":["India", "France", "Italy", "Japan", "South Korea", "Germany"],
"organisation":["ITC", "Google", "Facebook", "TATA", "Amazon", "Ford"],
```

Can anyone suggest.

Comment: by definition this is not a python dictionary.  a dictionary key is unique.  paste into jupyter your source "dictionary" and you get as expected unique keys for the last instance of the key.   what is generating the *invalid* dictionary / JSON?  fix at source is my suggestion

Comment: not me down voting,  just checking that requirement is to parse a certain format that work with **dict** have posted an answer

Comment: For background, see this earlier question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68753099/extracting-text-after-specific-character-set-from-a-text-file-using-regex-in-pyt

Answer (score 0):

- it's been established this is not a **dict**,  it's a LR(1) grammar that is similar to a JSON grammar
- taking this approach parse and tokenise it with an LR parser
- https://lark-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/json_tutorial.html shows how to parse JSON
- needs a small adaptation so that duplicate keys work (consider a **dict** as a **list**,  see code)
- have used **pandas** to take output from parser and reshape as you require

```
from lark import Transformer
from lark import Lark
import pandas as pd
json_parser = Lark(r"""
    ?value: dict
          | list
          | string
          | SIGNED_NUMBER      -> number
          | "true"             -> true
          | "false"            -> false
          | "null"             -> null

    list : "[" [value ("," value)*] "]"

    dict : "{" [pair ("," pair)*] "}"
    pair : string ":" value

    string : ESCAPED_STRING

    %import common.ESCAPED_STRING
    %import common.SIGNED_NUMBER
    %import common.WS
    %ignore WS

    """, start='value')
class TreeToJson(Transformer):
    def string(self, s):
        (s,) = s
        return s[1:-1]
    def number(self, n):
        (n,) = n
        return float(n)

    list = list
    pair = tuple
    dict = list # deal with issue of repeating keys...

    null = lambda self, _: None
    true = lambda self, _: True
    false = lambda self, _: False

js = """{
    "city":["New York", "Paris", "London"],
    "country":["India", "France", "Italy"],
    "city":["New Delhi", "Tokio", "Wuhan"],
    "organisation":["ITC", "Google", "Facebook"],
    "country":["Japan", "South Korea", "Germany"],
    "organisation":["TATA", "Amazon", "Ford"]
}"""    
    
tree = json_parser.parse(js)

pd.DataFrame(TreeToJson().transform(tree), columns=["key", "list"]).explode(
    "list"
).groupby("key").agg({"list": lambda s: s.unique().tolist()}).to_dict()["list"]
```

#### output

```
{'city': ['New York', 'Paris', 'London', 'New Delhi', 'Tokio', 'Wuhan'],
 'country': ['India', 'France', 'Italy', 'Japan', 'South Korea', 'Germany'],
 'organisation': ['ITC', 'Google', 'Facebook', 'TATA', 'Amazon', 'Ford']}
```

Comment: getting error UnexpectedCharacters: No terminal matches '"' in the current parser context, at line 5 col 2

 "7 KARNES": ["7 KARNES"],
        ^
Expected one of: 
 * RBRACE
 * COMMA
while running the code on larger data set where I also had non duplicate keys

Comment: can you provide me with a larger data set and I'll take a look.  I would expect it to work with any valid "bits" of JSON.  If the bits are malformed it will cause an issue