# Faster method to extract information from complex nested json in python dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, performance

I have some complex nested json data saved in a python dataframe column and I am trying to flatten the data into columns. The functions and method I have tested seem very slow and would take days to process all my data, so not really a good option.

I am reproducing a simplified example of the data below, and repeating the records to demonstrate how the number of records affect the processing time. Note: not all records have information for all the existing columns.

Please let me know of any other ways to improve the speed of that process. Thanks

```
import pandas as pd
str_json= {"json_col":[ '{"DayId":1,"Details":[{"LocationId":101,"Items":[{"Stock":[["A1",100],["A2",105],["A3",90],["A4",85]],"Product":"A"},{"Stock":[["B1",220],["B2",240]],"Product":"B"},{"Stock":[["C1",50]],"Product":"C"},{"Sold":[["A1",5],["A2",8],["A3",4]],"Product":"A"},{"Sold":[["C1",12]],"Product":"C"}]}]}','{"DayId":2,"Details":[{"LocationId":101,"Items":[{"Stock":[["D1",150],["D2",145],["D3",130]],"Product":"D"}]}]}','{"DayId":3,"Details":[{"LocationId":101,"Items":[{"Stock":[["A2",97],["A5",90]],"Product":"A"},{"Stock":[["E1",25],["E2",30],["E3",22],["E4",30]],"Product":"E"},{"Sold":[["B2",32]],"Product":"B"},{"Sold":[["D1",20],["D3",15]],"Product":"D"},{"Sold":[["E2",4],["E3",1],["E4",2]],"Product":"E"}]}]}']}


small_df = pd.DataFrame(str_json)
```

Example of small_df:
[image]

Creating a relatively bigger dataframe to illustrate how processing speed is affected with more records:

```
bigger_df = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(small_df.values, 1000, axis=0), columns=small_df.columns)
```

First function, step 1 (very slow). Extracting columns day_id, location_id and details_items:

```
def extract_details(row):
   data = row.to_string(header=False, index=False)
   json_data = json.loads(data)
   result = pd.json_normalize(json_data)
   day_id = result.iloc[0].loc['DayId']    
   details = result.iloc[0].loc['Details']

   details_df = pd.json_normalize(details)   
   location_id = details_df.iloc[0].loc['LocationId']
   details_items = details_df.iloc[0].loc['Items']

   return day_id, location_id, details_items


%%time
step1_df= bigger_df.copy()
step1_df[['day_id', 'location_id', 'details_items']]= step1_df.apply(lambda row: extract_details(row), axis=1, result_type ='expand')
step1_df.drop('json_col', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Example of step 1 running time and output:
[image]

Second function, step 2 (relatively fast):

```
def flatten_nested_json_df(df):

df = df.reset_index()

print(f"original shape: {df.shape}")
print(f"original columns: {df.columns}")


# search for columns to explode/flatten
s = (df.applymap(type) == list).all()
list_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

s = (df.applymap(type) == dict).all()
dict_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

print(f"lists: {list_columns}, dicts: {dict_columns}")
while len(list_columns) > 0 or len(dict_columns) > 0:
    new_columns = []

    for col in dict_columns:
        print(f"flattening: {col}")
        # explode dictionaries horizontally, adding new columns
        horiz_exploded = pd.json_normalize(df[col]).add_prefix(f'{col}.')
        horiz_exploded.index = df.index
        df = pd.concat([df, horiz_exploded], axis=1).drop(columns=[col])
        new_columns.extend(horiz_exploded.columns) # inplace

    for col in list_columns:
        print(f"exploding: {col}")
        # explode lists vertically, adding new columns
        df = df.drop(columns=[col]).join(df[col].explode().to_frame())
        new_columns.append(col)

    # check if there are still dict o list fields to flatten
    s = (df[new_columns].applymap(type) == list).all()
    list_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

    s = (df[new_columns].applymap(type) == dict).all()
    dict_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

    print(f"lists: {list_columns}, dicts: {dict_columns}")

print(f"final shape: {df.shape}")
print(f"final columns: {df.columns}")
return df
```

Example of step 2 running time and output:
[image]

Comment: consider writing a custom LR(1) json parser / transformer.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68756628/how-to-merge-values-of-multiple-keys-with-the-same-name-using-python/68758831#68758831 you can optimise how you transform the parse tree

Answer (score 1):

- here's a different approach.  Put in place a parser / transformer that generates a **dict** that can be flattened by `json_normalize()` in a single call
- output structure is generic fully flattened,  hence column names include index of embedded **list**
- timings below - it's not clear to me what timings you are seeing
- opportunities for further optimisation of output from transformer (output less).  However this would make it less generic

#### create specialised JSON parser

```
from lark import Transformer
from lark import Lark

json_grammar = r"""
    ?value: dict
          | list
          | string
          | SIGNED_NUMBER      -> number
          | "true"             -> true
          | "false"            -> false
          | "null"             -> null

    list : "[" [value ("," value)*] "]"

    dict : "{" [pair ("," pair)*] "}"
    pair : string ":" value

    string : ESCAPED_STRING

    %import common.ESCAPED_STRING
    %import common.SIGNED_NUMBER
    %import common.WS
    %ignore WS

    """
class TreeToJson(Transformer):
    def string(self, s):
        (s,) = s
        return s[1:-1]
    def number(self, n):
        (n,) = n
        return float(n)
    # convert embedded lists to embedded dicts
    def list(self, l):
        return {str(i):v for i,v in enumerate(l)}
    pair = tuple
    dict = dict 

    null = lambda self, _: None
    true = lambda self, _: True
    false = lambda self, _: False

json_parser = Lark(json_grammar, start='value', parser='lalr', transformer=TreeToJson())
```

#### app code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
str_json= {"json_col":[ '{"DayId":1,"Details":[{"LocationId":101,"Items":[{"Stock":[["A1",100],["A2",105],["A3",90],["A4",85]],"Product":"A"},{"Stock":[["B1",220],["B2",240]],"Product":"B"},{"Stock":[["C1",50]],"Product":"C"},{"Sold":[["A1",5],["A2",8],["A3",4]],"Product":"A"},{"Sold":[["C1",12]],"Product":"C"}]}]}','{"DayId":2,"Details":[{"LocationId":101,"Items":[{"Stock":[["D1",150],["D2",145],["D3",130]],"Product":"D"}]}]}','{"DayId":3,"Details":[{"LocationId":101,"Items":[{"Stock":[["A2",97],["A5",90]],"Product":"A"},{"Stock":[["E1",25],["E2",30],["E3",22],["E4",30]],"Product":"E"},{"Sold":[["B2",32]],"Product":"B"},{"Sold":[["D1",20],["D3",15]],"Product":"D"},{"Sold":[["E2",4],["E3",1],["E4",2]],"Product":"E"}]}]}']}

small_df = pd.DataFrame(str_json)

def wide(js):
    df = pd.json_normalize(json_parser.parse(js))
    return pd.Series(df.values[0], index=df.columns)

bigger_df = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(small_df.values, 1000, axis=0), columns=small_df.columns)
small_df["json_col"].apply(wide)
```

##### output

|  | DayId | Details.0.LocationId | Details.0.Items.0.Stock.0.0 | Details.0.Items.0.Stock.0.1 | Details.0.Items.0.Stock.1.0 | Details.0.Items.0.Stock.1.1 | Details.0.Items.0.Stock.2.0 | Details.0.Items.0.Stock.2.1 | Details.0.Items.0.Stock.3.0 | Details.0.Items.0.Stock.3.1 | Details.0.Items.0.Product | Details.0.Items.1.Stock.0.0 | Details.0.Items.1.Stock.0.1 | Details.0.Items.1.Stock.1.0 | Details.0.Items.1.Stock.1.1 | Details.0.Items.1.Product | Details.0.Items.2.Stock.0.0 | Details.0.Items.2.Stock.0.1 | Details.0.Items.2.Product | Details.0.Items.3.Sold.0.0 | Details.0.Items.3.Sold.0.1 | Details.0.Items.3.Sold.1.0 | Details.0.Items.3.Sold.1.1 | Details.0.Items.3.Sold.2.0 | Details.0.Items.3.Sold.2.1 | Details.0.Items.3.Product | Details.0.Items.4.Sold.0.0 | Details.0.Items.4.Sold.0.1 | Details.0.Items.4.Product | Details.0.Items.1.Stock.2.0 | Details.0.Items.1.Stock.2.1 | Details.0.Items.1.Stock.3.0 | Details.0.Items.1.Stock.3.1 | Details.0.Items.2.Sold.0.0 | Details.0.Items.2.Sold.0.1 | Details.0.Items.4.Sold.1.0 | Details.0.Items.4.Sold.1.1 | Details.0.Items.4.Sold.2.0 | Details.0.Items.4.Sold.2.1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 101 | A1 | 100 | A2 | 105 | A3 | 90 | A4 | 85 | A | B1 | 220 | B2 | 240 | B | C1 | 50 | C | A1 | 5 | A2 | 8 | A3 | 4 | A | C1 | 12 | C | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 1 | 2 | 101 | D1 | 150 | D2 | 145 | D3 | 130 | nan | nan | D | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 2 | 3 | 101 | A2 | 97 | A5 | 90 | nan | nan | nan | nan | A | E1 | 25 | E2 | 30 | E | nan | nan | B | D1 | 20 | D3 | 15 | nan | nan | D | E2 | 4 | E | E3 | 22 | E4 | 30 | B2 | 32 | E3 | 1 | E4 | 2 |

#### timing

- parsing and transforming < 1ms
- parsing, transforming and creation of series ~2ms
- parsing, transforming, creation of series and results in data frame ~3.5ms
- processing 3000 rows, 5.5s

```
%timeit json_parser.parse(small_df.values[0][0])
%timeit wide(small_df.values[0][0])
%timeit small_df.loc[0, ["json_col"]].apply(wide)
%timeit bigger_df["json_col"].apply(wide)
864 µs ± 8.22 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
1.99 ms ± 83.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
3.55 ms ± 117 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
5.49 s ± 529 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: I am seeing a KeyError: '0' when copying/pasting and running the suggested method. Not sure what would be the difference and the reason.

Comment: is it this line `json_parser.parse(small_df.values[0][0])` line of code that fails?  try `json_parser.parse("""{"a":1,"b":{"c":[5,6]}}""")`

Comment: json_parser.parse("""{"a":1,"b":{"c":[5,6]}}""") returns {'a': 1.0, 'b': {'c': {0: 5.0, 1: 6.0}}}

Comment: good,  therefore `pd.DataFrame([{"js":"""{"a":1,"b":{"c":[5,6]}}"""}])["js"].apply(wide)` should work and return a dataframe with 3 columns.  Which line gave the key error?

Comment: ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_normalize.py in _json_normalize(data, record_path, meta, meta_prefix, record_prefix, errors, sep, max_level)
    276             # TODO: handle record value which are lists, at least error
    277             #       reasonably
--> 278             data = nested_to_record(data, sep=sep, max_level=max_level)
    279         return DataFrame(data)
    280     elif not isinstance(record_path, list):
...
KeyError: '0'

Comment: what pandas version? I'm using 1.3.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235995/discussion-between-wyse09-and-rob-raymond).

Comment: The updated alternative ran with my pandas v1.3.1. I then did a comparison of the execution speed which unfortunately didn't improve. I'll try and do the pre-processing in postgresql beforehand and see how it compares. Thank you very much for your assistance which was much appreciated!