# Regular Expression to find three hyphens, separated by numbers or nothing, in a disc file name to get series and episode numbers

Tags: regex

I need to identify disc files that have three hyphens in the name that may or may not be separated by numbers. The regex needs to be able to cater for this occurring at the end of the file name. I have come up with the following but am sure that there is a more elegant and efficient way to achieve what I want:

```cs
string sRegex = @"--[-|.]|-[\d]-[-|.]|--[\d][-|.]|-[\d]-[\d][-|.]";
```

examples of matching file names are:

```
Ice Cold Murders- Rocco Schiavone-1-5.ts
Lost Girl---Where There's a Will, There's a Fae_Pick_2019_04_09_20_00.ts
Lost Girl-1-4-Food For Thought_Pick_2019_04_15_20_00.ts
```

The three hyphens may only be separated by integers or nothing and the numbers represent series number and episode number.

I am writing an app that enters episode numbers starting from a given series and episode number as a series.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't understand what square brackets mean in regex. They do not act like brackets; they delimit a character class. For example `[-|.]` matches a single character that is either a `-`, a`|` or a `.`. Also `[\d]` is identical to just `\d`. Read [What is the difference between square brackets and parentheses in a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801630/what-is-the-difference-between-square-brackets-and-parentheses-in-a-regex)

Comment: Why does `Ice Cold Murders- Rocco Schiavone-1-5.ts` match? There are only 2 hyphens (separated by digits).

Comment: You can group hyphens with optional digits and shorten your expression to something like `(?:-\d*){2}[-.]`.

Comment: Thank you, Bohemian, for pointing that out. I should have put [-.] and, yes, the bracket around \d is superfluous.

Comment: The regex needs to allow three hyphens separated by nothing or integers or two hyphens and a point at the end of the file name separated by nothing or integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your pattern, you want to match either a hyphen or a dot with `[-|.]` which you can write as `[-.]` without the pipe (it would match the pipe literally if it is there)

Matching 3 hyphens separated by either a dot or hyphen might be shortened to:

```
-(?:\d*[-.]){2}
```

**Explanation**

- `-` Match literally
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\d*` match optional digits
  - `[-.]` Match either `-` or `.`
- `){2}` Close the non capture group and repeat it 2 times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9tQETr/1)

If the whole pattern should end on `.ts` then:

```
.*(?:-\d*){2}(?=[.-]).*\.ts$
```

Or a bit more broader match:

```
.*(?:-\d*){2}(?=[.-]).*\.[^\s.]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mNilJy/1)

**Edit**

If the third occurrence can only by a hyphen or dot:

```
-\d*-\d*[.-]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tKZwSV/1)

Comment: -(?:\d*[-.]){2} worked for all of my examples. I didn't include the extension because this regex needs to support all video file types.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the point can only come third; i.e. after the episode number. Is it possible to make your solution do that?

Comment: @TonyVaughan You could use `-\d*-\d*[.-]` See https://regex101.com/r/tKZwSV/1

Comment: -\d*-\d*[.-] - that's the one I was looking for. I had missed the possibility to have \d* - where the integer is optional - in tutorials. It really simplifies everything.

Comment: @TonyVaughan Great that it works out. If any of the posted answers works out for you, please consider accepting an answer.

Comment: Absolutely. I am trying to find where to accept your answer on this page but can't see it:). Ah, I see it now.

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for your comments. It's been an education.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping it simple, you could use this pattern:

```
^.*(?:-[^-]*){2}-.*\.\w+$
```

This matches:

- `^` from the start of the filename

  - `.*` match optional leading portion
  - `(?:-[^-]*){2}` match two hyphen separated components
  - `-` match a required third hyphen
  - `.*` followed by any other content
  - `\.\w+` ending with dot and an extension
- `$` end of the filename

### Demo

Comment: This worked for every one except Ice Cold Murders- Rocco Schiavone-1-5.ts

Comment: ...and why would you expect a match in this case given that the filenamw has only _two_, not three, hyphens?